# Java Encode file to Base64 string To match with other encoded string

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, base64

```
private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(String fileName)
        throws IOException {

    File file = new File(fileName);
    byte[] bytes = loadFile(file);
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
    String encodedString = new String(encoded,StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

    return encodedString;
}
private static byte[] loadFile(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    long length = file.length();
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        // File is too large
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length
           && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
    }

    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

// to get encode string

```
String encoded=encodeFileToBase64Binary("file.fmr");
```

// encoded string is :

```
Rk1SACAyMAAAAAFiAAABQAHgAMUAxQEAAABGNkDZADP/SEC8AD6CSECqAEcGSED+AFJtO0CgAGCKZEC6AGuFZEDgAHz1ZECzAI6HZEENAJluNEBWAJ4ZZEB1AKkTZEECALbuZEA/ALqfSECCALySSECxAMP/ZECIAMURVUAXAN2jGkCnAOD8ZEAoAOWlZEBnAOyhLkCyAP/tZECHAQMSGkD8AQTdZECfASKFGkCHASUaGkA1ASy6ZEDAAS3JZEDPAS7NZEAnATG4ZEDxATzOZEBOAUPLZEBzAVbuGkCAAWF8NEDTAWsxLkDnAXa0LkC/AX2nLkC0AYojIEBMAYvkSEDJAa0fT0CsAbwVIIDqANTsZIDIAPfnZICbAQKHO4D5AR/XZIBlASS7IIEoASbYO4CsAUetLoDvAVXSZIDaAVvDO4EHAWrLZICsAX2fNIDnAYEwNIDQAZKnT4BfAZxtZAAA
```

//encoded string from file using some other source.

```
Rk1SACAyMAAAAAFiAAABQAHgAMUAxQEAAABGNkCLACELSEDAADYDZEEYAGFxO0DGAGJ9SEC1AGkCSEA6AHWYVUDJAHp5ZEBEAHwVZECVAJgIZEEaALHrZEB4ALuOZEELAMFqZEEzAM/sNEDRANvwZEBkAN0VZECcAOIAZEEwAOjnLkEvAPXlO0CnAP71ZEB7AQYRNEBdAQ0eZED8ARDhZEDXASXcZECZAS3uGkBoAT4eO0AUAUMxSEA7AUYqZEDxAUnSZECmAVNDO0EIAXDHSEDYAXW7ZEEUAXXKSEEGAYY8IEEhAYrDNEDfAZ81ZEDQAcGqLoEBAC/7O4EGAE7zVYB+AP2QSICEARuLZIBnATUfO4D/ATXaZIDEATjSZIDRATrVZICnATvSNIBTATwnZIARAV1LGoB1AV2oO4CrAV68SIDnAWHGZIB+AWauNICVAX0ySICNAYytO4CJAZorSAAA
```

When i am trying to match both the encoded string , i am getting a missmatch.
please suggest method for encode file to base64 to match encoded string found from other source.
i have tried with `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` and `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`.

Answer (score 39):

You already using apache commons-codec so I recommend adding commons-io for reading the file. That way you can remove your loadFile() method and just have:

```
private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(String fileName) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
    return new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. but i am getting same result in encoding.

Comment: I tested this with several files and an external Base64 encoder. Can you provide an example file?

Comment: facing a problem ,  Base64.encodeBase64(); cannot be resolved why?

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris you need import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; in order to use Base64.encodeBase64() you get the JAR from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/

Answer (score 34):

Here is a solution without any required dependencies (*Apacha et al.*) requiring only JDK 8+:

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.nio.file.Files;

private static String encodeFileToBase64(File file) {
    try {
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("could not read file " + file, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Java 8 you can use the class `java.util.Base64` and the corresponding inner classes:

- `java.util.Base64.Encoder`
- `java.util.Base64.Decoder`

See JavaDoc: [Base64-Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)

And a sample for the use: [Example from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/Base64Sample.java)

Answer (score 2):

This example worked great for me: https://grokonez.com/java/java-advanced/java-8-encode-decode-an-image-base64

```
public static String encoder(String filePath) {
        String base64File = "";
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try (FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            // Reading a file from file system
            byte fileData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            imageInFile.read(fileData);
            base64File = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileData);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found" + e);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception while reading the file " + ioe);
        }
        return base64File;
    }
```