# how i can read files as bytes then encode it to base64 in java ( android )

Tags: java, file-io

How can I read files as bytes and then encode it to base64 by java with low api like : api level 17?

I tried this code to convert files to base64:

[Java Encode file to Base64 string To match with other encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066216/java-encode-file-to-base64-string-to-match-with-other-encoded-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File file = new File(filepath);
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent.getBytes());
```

For old api use 
`FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File file)` 
or 
`IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input)`.

Comment: Could you please put all of your answer in the answer.